# Django Template Save operation result into a variable

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a listing counter "2370" and the page only shows "12" item so I want to calculate the pages number, I did the solution below

```
{% widthratio listing.total_count 12 1 %}
```

so, how I can save the result into a variable?

```
{% set total_pages =  widthratio listing.total_count 12 1 %}
```

this one didn't work

Comment: Don't think that is possible. Try to calculated and pass `total_pages` from view to template.

Comment: You would like to use `{% with blah as blue %}` but chaining template tags isn't possible so you're going to have to resort to writing your own template tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If would choose Rohans comment, but if you would write your own templatetags, use an `assignment_tag` (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-template-tags/#assignment-tags, exists since Django 1.4).

```
@register.assignment_tag
def page_numbers(total_items, items_per_page):
    if not total_items:
         return 0
    # int divisions round down (1 / 12 = 0), so just add 1 to cover this 
    return total_items / items_per_page + 1
```

Within the template you should use;

```
{% page_numbers listing.total_count 12 as page_nrs %}
```